# Storage of live game data in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm planning to program a gameserver in Laravel. (Web)clients should connect via a REST API and do things as starting the game or answering questions. Is it a good practice to store data like the current score of each player or countdowns which decrement each second in a database? I think it would be slow but where else can such data which has to be accessible by every new API request be stored nicely?

Comment: Yeah, thats typically where you'd want to store the data. and as far as countdowns go, it might be easier to store the last time the action the countdown is representing as unix timestamps of the last time the action was completed

Comment: Derek’s comment is correct. You need to define precomputed for the countdown timer if you really want them to sync well. Also, take a look at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting.

Comment: Thanks, just for curiosity: will this result in writing changes to the disk every time I make a change on a database model or will the changes be made in RAM and only written to the disk from time to time?